# How to model a freight container's warehouse storage system in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

[Context]

I'm modeling the operations of a freight container warehouse, where empty freight containers are stored while awaiting the request from the shipping company that owns each container (for example, Mediterranean Shipping Company, MSC).

I intend to design the process of unloading containers from the trucks that deliver them to the warehouse. These containers are then lifted using a forklift (though in reality, a container crane performs this task), and subsequently stored in specific areas. My challenge lies within the storage aspect.

[Problem]

I've attempted to utilize the Storage, Store, and Retrieve blocks from the Material Handling library. However, they do not align with the actual operations since they are designed for rack systems. In our case, containers can be stored vertically or horizontally, and they cannot be retrieved independently (unlike rack systems, where items can be retrieved from any cell).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8wcy.png)

As shown in the illustration, we have a traditional layout of containers, along with a container crane. These cranes can only lift containers from the sides (for instance, containers H and D in the image). Given this constraint, if I need to retrieve container B, I would first need to retrieve containers D, C, and G, or alternatively, containers H, F, A, and G. Each container is treated as a distinct agent in my model due to their unique IDs. This distinction is important as the shipping company specifies a particular container each time they make a request, and the key of the model is to find the best storage policy to optimize crane movements in order to fulfill a request.

Could anyone assist me in resolving this issue so that the model accurately represents the real-life scenario?

Kind regards,
Lucas